Can I use env inside href="" of <a> tag in docusauras docs?
I'm trying to implement a link in my Docusaurus project that redirects users to a registration page. However, I'm facing challenges because the registration page is hosted on a different port and domain. When I set the link like this:
<a href="/">Home</a>

it redirects to the home page .
I need to use an environment variable to set the link dynamically, but I'm unable to do so directly in the href attribute. I attempted the following:
<a href="<EnvValue name='dashboardURL'/>/register">Register</a>

However, this results in a URL like http://localhost:8001/docs/%3CEnvValue%20name='dashboardURL'/%3E/register, which is not what I want. Instead, I want to redirect to the actual domain specified by the environment variable dashboardURL.
Is there a way to achieve this in Docusaurus? How can I correctly implement an external link using an environment variable for the URL? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Note: This env <EnvValue name='dashboardURL'/> works outside the href.


<EnvValue name='dashboardURL'/> is this your custom react component?

NO I am using docusauras, for my landing page.

I'm not sure why you would load an environment variable using a component like
<EnvValue name='dashboardURL'/>

Typically, you can just load the environment variable using process.env, like this
process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_dashboardURL

So your final code will look something like this
<a href={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_dashboardURL}/register`}>Register</a>

Do note that, you have to prefix the environment variable with NEXT_PUBLIC_ so it is available on the browser.

By default, environment variables are only available on the server. To expose an environment variable to the browser, it must be prefixed with NEXT_PUBLIC_.

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#runtime-environment-variables

<a href={${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_dashboardURL}/register}>Register That doesn't work on markdown file in docusauras. I have to use env beacause my other pages are running on different port. So, I can not just redirect like href="dashboar". My docusauas is running on a port and my apps other part is on another port that's the issue.
